# trying to hide something when input selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mitchbregs/M2Z88/2/)

Everything is written in the fiddle.

What the problem is: 
I want the text to disappear when I select to start typing something in my input.

1. If i focus on the input, I want the

   to disappear, and only reappear if i havent typed anything in,
2. If i have something typed in my text input, i want the hide to stay that way.

I honestly have no clue how to do this, and i gave a bs attempt at it to show what i mean

thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Note that the 'placeholder' attribute is not recognized by Internet Explorer before version 10: http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) to detect when the input loses focus, and then test if its length is  `0` using [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/). If it is, `show` the `p` again:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $(".type").focus(function() {
        $("p").hide();
    }).blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
            $("p").show();
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/M2Z88/4/)**.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mitchbregs/FjxaU/ -- this is what im trying to do.. im trying to get the advanced search text out -- can u help me out?

Comment: @Mitchell: Sure, but I think it's working. The problem is you forgot to include jquery in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FjxaU/1/

Comment: take a look at this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Z7bnrDP2 --- if u run it, its not working for some reason

Comment: @Mitchell: Oh, I see, you need to wrap your `<script>` code in `$(document).ready`. Otherwise, you'll try to bind the event `focus` to an element that does not yet exist. Take a look at my update.

Comment: An alternative is to put your `script` block at the *end* of the page, when `big_search` was already loaded. Note that this works on jsFiddle, because jsFiddle automatically adds that for you.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0jGPM0fQ @joao -- still not working :(.. sorry to be bothering u

Comment: still having problems -- can u edit my pastebin and repaste it? id appreciate it!

Comment: @Mitchell: What's the link of your latest pastebin? The last one you posted still has the error I mentioned. Check this one http://pastebin.com/gWMZh48k.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2wyGdziT -- sorry im bothering you! -- the one you gave me still not working lol (edited)

Comment: @Mitchell: I pasted that entire code into jsfiddle, and it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/kxPnZ/. Are you sure you're testing the most recent version? What exactly isn't working? Can you check the fiddle and see if it works ok for you?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is some error in the fiddle that you are trying to run.. I created a new fiddle and seems to be working fine for some reason..

```
​$('.type').on('focus', function(){
    $("p").hide();         
});

$('.type').on('keyup blur', function(){
    if($('.type').val() == ''){
        $("p").show();       
    }
});
```

​Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/FcDVE/)

Use the keyup and blur events to get the functionality you want..

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yLK5c/3/

```
    $(".type").on('focus keyUp',function(){ 
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).attr('placeholder',"");
        }            
});
      $(".type").blur(function(){ 
          if ($(this).val() == "") {
             $('p').hide();           
          } else {
          $('p').show(); 
          }             
        $(this).attr('placeholder',"type something");    
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle to work, use 'on', and use blur.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".type").on('focus', function(){ 
        $("p.explanatory").hide();            
    }).on('blur', function() { 
        if($('.type').val() == '')
        {
            $("p.explanatory").show();      
        }
    });

});
```

Here is my work!
http://jsfiddle.net/M2Z88/5/

Answer (score 0):

As João points out, you should use the `blur` event to detect when you lose focus.  However, it appears additionally you want the text to disappear if there's any text in the text box.  The way to do that to listen for `keyup` events and then check the value that's in the edit box.  (If you use `keydown`, the letter will not be added to the text box, so you'll be a character behind.)

I think what you want is this:

```
$(".type").focus(function(){ 
    if( $(this).val() == '' ) $("p").hide();
});
$(".type").blur(function(){
    $("p").show();
});
$(".type").keyup(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == '' ) $("p").hide();
    else $("p").show();
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mz95q/

Comment: well, see as you start typing, the <p> shows up again.. i want it so that when im typing it disappears and if someting is typed, then it stays hidden

Comment: I see.  That wasn't clear.  I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: also, http://jsfiddle.net/mitchbregs/FjxaU/ -- this is the point of what im doing.. im trying to get rid of the "Advanced search"

Answer (score 0):

Here is my recipe

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".type")
    .focus(function(){
        $("p").hide()
    ;})
    .blur(function () {
      if (!$(this).val()) {
        $("p").show()
      ;}
    });
});
```